# Как записать и считать файл из FilesDir

Tags: android, файлы, null

Добрый день. 
Вроде как, если я правильно читал, то у директории

```
data/data/my_app/files
```

есть права на запись и чтение.

Но когда я пытаюсь записать что либо в файл, то вылазит ошибка null.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/file.json");
byte a[] = "aaa".getBytes();
fos.write(a);
fos.close();
```

Как можно записывать и считывать файлы оттуда?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё очень просто:

For example:

```
      String FILENAME = "hello_file";
      String string = "hello world!";

      FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      fos.write(string.getBytes());
      fos.close();
```

Источник : [Using the Internal Storage (developer.android.com)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Читать вообще-то есть много вариантов погугли на эту тему. Один из вариантов:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
             openFileInput(FILENAME)));         
        String string = "";          
        String buf;        
        while ((buf = br.readLine()) != null) {      
            string += buf;       
        }
```

Comment: @wonesss, да, таким образом работает (так делал ранее), но когда я пытаюсь читать, то приходится читать в буфер указанного размера. А я не могу знать сколько символов в файле. Как быть?

Comment: @woesss , сделал, пока вроде работает. Спасибо.

Comment: @woesss , я пробовал дофигища вариантов. И в конце концов запутался очень сильно. Хотя этот вариант реально работал по всей видимости с самого начала. 
Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по документации, функция **getFilesDir()** имеет тип возвращаемого значения **File**

Соответственно в строке

> getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/file.json"

идет преобразование типа **File** к **String**, а это помоему не гарантирует того, что тип **File** будет после этого как раз нужной директорией

Попробуйте так:

`getFilesDir().getPath()`

Comment: @Роман Захаров, попробовал так:
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath()+"/users.json"));
Все равно ругается на ошибку.

Comment: добавь стек ошибки к вопросу, попробуем разобраться

Comment: @Роман Захаров, я пошел по пути второго ответа на мой вопрос. Там вроде все работает...по крайней мере я так думаю.) 

Спасибо.